# Do all cameras that are ONVIF compliant provide JPEG over RTP?

Tags: rtsp, rtp, ip-camera, onvif

I'm reading [ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf](https://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf) and section `5.1.4 JPEG over RTP` describes the JPEG streams format over RTP. Does this mean that to be ONVIF compliant, an IP camera should provide this feature? In the other words, what are the chances that a camera that is advertised as ONVIF compliant provides JPEG over RTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONVIF compliant IP Camera should have tested through ONVIF Device TestTool without any fail.

There are ONVIF profiles; S, G, C, Q, A.
However, in relation to your question, 
The ONVIF compliant IP camera should be meet with [ONVIF Profile S](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/profile-s/).

The test case for ONVIF Conformance include JPEG over RTP; 
The ID of the test case is

> "RTSS-1-1-53 MEDIA STREAMING – JPEG (VALIDATING RTP HEADER EXTENSION)" in ONVIF Device Test Tool version 16.07 SR2

ONVIF Compliant IP camera should have at least Video Codec with JPEG(MJPEG); optional MPEG4, H.264.
If the compliant IP camera have audio function, it should have at least G.711

---

The ONVIF Device Test Tool by the ONVIF organization, initially detects the features of the IP Camera. 
Therefore, the test case is automatically selected based on the detected function.

The Profile S compatible IP Camera must meet the selected test cases.
Test cases are mandatory, conditional(madatory if supported) and optional

Comment: Is there a place I can download the ONVIF Device Test Tool from? Thanks.

Comment: You can get the ONVIF Device Test Tool in the ONVIF Forum.
http://developer.onvif.org
First you have to be one of ONVIF member.

Answer (score 1):

For ONVIF Profile T it's mandatory:
https://www.onvif.org/profiles/profile-t/